# DAX Running Stock Total

Tags: powerbi, dax, data-analysis

We are trying to get a predicted running stock total using inbounds and sales forecast. We keep running into cyclic errors, referencing the column we are creating in the formula. I will explain this as best as i can.
I understand how to do Cumulative sales etc, but because there are negative months involved, we are really struggling.

We have got:

[image: Product Code | Week | Inbounds | Sales | Net ABC | 04/12/2023 | 0 | 1000 | -1000 ABC | 11/12/2023 | 1500 | 1000| 500]

I would like the running total for these row to be:

[image]

We can't change Net to MAX(Net,0) because when the running total is ABOVE 0 we need to take off the Net.
So doing a SUM of 'Net' using EARLIER would return the below:

[image]

The only way that i can think is to Reference Running Total in the Running Total formula to get the previous month's stock position, but that just wont work?

Essentially, i think that whenever the running total reaches 0 it should stay at 0 until 'Net' > 0

Any help would be appreciated.